# Changing python version on platform LSF job script on Linux server

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, lsf

I want to execute my python code on LSF, and problem is that the return of

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

in lsf is

> 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 22 2015, 16:47:47) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)]

But my code has been written for python2.7. How can I change or assign the correct version of python to LSF job script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to change the current version of python. with the following steps:

```
$ module avail
$ module unload python/2.6.6
$ module load python/2.7.9
```